# My builds keep failing in Vercel when I push from GitHub, saying ESLint error?

Tags: deployment, build, next.js, vercel, build-error

My GitHub is hooked up to Vercel, and every time I push, it should deploy. It was working as it should - but then stopped. The main problem I am seeing is

> error - ESLint: ESLint configuration in .eslintrc.json is invalid:     - Property "parser" is the wrong type (expected string/null but got `["@babel/eslint-parser"]`).

and then the last line reads:

> Error: Command "next build" exited with 1

I have read through previous posts, and tried all things I've seen recommended to fix this issue, but I still cannot get a successful build. Any advice?

Comment: Can you show us your `.eslintrc.json` file?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should just use "@babel/eslint-parser" for the parser option, no brackets, it should just be a string.